# How to normalize(min/max) specific column in python? (Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have been working on normalizing the data based on Min-Max Normalization.
My datasets are data frames stored in df_mols list like below.

```
df_mols[0]:   
         frequency  Molecule0
 0        -326.0   2.604015
 1        -323.0   2.624186
 2        -321.0   2.644598
 3        -318.0   2.665254
 4        -316.0   2.686159
 ...         ...        ...
 1996     4589.0   4.565467
 1997     4591.0   4.512142
 1998     4594.0   4.459744
 1999     4596.0   4.408251
 2000     4598.0   4.357645
 
df_mols[1]:      
          frequency  Molecule1
 0        -357.0   0.368472
 1        -354.0   0.371063
 2        -352.0   0.373683
 3        -350.0   0.376332
 4        -347.0   0.379010
 ...         ...        ...
 1996     4293.0   0.538391
 1997     4295.0   0.532088
 1998     4297.0   0.525894
 1999     4300.0   0.519807
 2000        NaN        NaN
```

I want to normailize only all the Molecule columns.
What I did so far was,

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler=MinMaxScaler()

for i in df_mols:
  i['frequency']=i['frequency'].apply(np.rint) # This was to make frequency values into int
  i[:,1]=scaler.fit_transform(i[:,1])
```

and had error like below

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    554                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    555                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 556                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    557 
    558         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[2.60401472 2.62418641 2.64459837 ... 4.45974369 4.4082515  4.35764454].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I tried to reshape but couldn't do it. should I make new series and then update the value? or I should I figure this problem?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Before reshaping, you can use object method `.to_numpy()` to convert your pd.Series to np.ndarray.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its what you're looking for but I think something like this would do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

data = [[-326.0, 2.604015], [-323.0, 2.624186], [-321.0, 2.644598], [-318.0, 2.665254]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['frequency', 'Molecule0'])

print("Shape of column: ", df['Molecule0'].shape)

normalized_data = normalize(df['Molecule0'].to_numpy().reshape(1, -1), norm='max')[0]

print("Normalized data: ", normalized_data)

df['Molecule0'] = normalized_data
print(df)
```

When I ran this I got the following output...

**Shape of column:  (4,)

Normalized data:  [0.9770232  0.98459134 0.99224989 1.        ]


frequency  Molecule0

0     -326.0   0.977023

1     -323.0   0.984591

2     -321.0   0.992250

3     -318.0   1.000000**

Comment: Thank you ! However, What if there are almost 70 molecules so that I want to make the change with for loop?/ generic version?

Comment: @sopL Are all of the molecules in the same dataframe?

Comment: No, each molecules are in different dataframes but same iloc[1]( ex: [frequency, Molecule0],[frequency, Molecule1],), and the dataframes in df_mols(list).

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. df_mol[0]= it's a Series with 'frequency' and 'Molecule0' columns and for df_mol[1]=it's 'frequency' and 'Molecule1' columns